# Task which need to be reviewed on priority basis

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

How come the reviewer know the task is of high priority? Is there any provision for the client to inform the reviewer that the form need to review soon.

Also how the client came to know that the application submitted is rejected/returned?

Answer (score 0):

The client as a user isn't actually the one who should be setting the task as high priority. It should be either a admin user/ another reviewer user who is supposed to assign whether a task is of high priority or not. It can be done by setting Due dates in task details section to signify the task is of high priority and should be completed quickly.

[image]

To answer the second question, the client can know the application status by checking the application history tab and understand the progress of their application.

[image]